# WhatsApp voice call overrides iPhone's "do not disturb"

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app, do-not-disturb

I've noticed recently that even though my iPhone (running iOS 11.2.5) has "do not disturb" mode on at night, WhatsApp voice calls go through as usual. So far, the only solution I could come up with is turning vibrations off in the sounds settings. Is there a better way to handle this situation? If not, who should I contact in this case? Apple or WhatsApp?

Thank you!

Comment: Go to settings->do not disturb-> then check all the settings...

Comment: @Harcker Apologies, but I couldn’t find any helpful setting in there. Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: The ones to let call through (“allow calls from” and “repeating calls”, (I don’t have the correct English names))

Comment: This is definitely a regression. It used to work for sure.
And actually the Apple discussion linked on the agreed answer confirms it’s a bug.

Comment: A tip might be to check your DND settings—there is a flag that makes DND not have effect when device is unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. Do Not Disturb only enables Apple's features like phone and messages. It does not affect third-party applications.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7952191)

> It has nothing to do with Apple's software. Do not disturb only affects Apple's core iOS features - the telephone app, the messaging app and iOS notifications service.  It does not interact with or affect third party apps.

If you want Whatsapp to implement the feature you need to contact them:

> If you want WhatsApp to implement something similar, then you need to suggest it to the WhatsApp developers.  Or, close WhatsApp at night, and disable it in background app refresh in settings.

To provide a similar setting on Whatsapp you can close it at the desired time and turn on background app refresh which will prevent it from updating and receiving messages.

**To turn off background app refresh**

Go to Settings -> General -> Background app refresh and turn of Whatsapp.

To completely turn all apps of from refreshing click at the top where it says background app refresh and click off.

Comment: This is poor from Apple to be honest, they block notifications from 3rd party apps but not calls? Seems like a disjointed user experience :( this Apple page makes no mention of it not working under odd edge cases: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204321

Comment: WhatsApp on Android does not have this problem FWIW